# Base_url() issue with the anchor tag in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter and having trouble with link formation. In my page, I have a link to another page set to:

`<a href = "<?php base_url('feed');?>"><li>Feed Page</li></a>`

Here the feed is one of my `controller`s, but the link is showing as:

`http://localhost/BusinessPad/localhost/BusinessPad/feed`,

which doesn't actually exist. I can't understand how this happened; I have made sure: `$config['index_page'] = '';` and I added an `.htaccess` file. If I leave `$config['base_url']=''`, the `base URL` is still not working for me.

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is and what you are observing and what you are asking

Comment: in my url localhost/sitename/localhost/sitename/product this is working.hat actually doesn't exists. Can't understand how this happen.

Comment: You should use site_url() instead of base_url() and also Load url helper or autload url helper

Answer (score 2):

To deal with anchor tag, You can have like this

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>BusinessPad/feed">Feeds</a>
```

You shall put the `base_url` inside your anchor tag and then your controller name.

Then you will get the url like `localhost/BusinessPad/feed` which you expect.

Note : Make sure you have loaded the url helper by `$this->load->helper('url');` or loaded in `autoload` itself

Comment: http://example.com/productname in the URL this is fine for me But when I write http://example.com/http://example.com/productname/ on the url it give me the same result as http://example.com/productname. I think http://example.com/http://example.com/productname/ is invalid url it should not work

Comment: Yes, It should not, How you construct the url ?

Comment: Then just try this `<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/feed">Feeds</a>`

Comment: anchor link always take me to the right url but only the issue is with 
 
example.com/productname and  example.com/http://example.com/productname always work on wvery anchor tag

Comment: I think the issue is with .htaccess file can you please help with me that

Comment: Ah, `.htaccess` is not the actual problem, FIrst can i know how you construct the `http://example.com/productname` ?

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) sitename/$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sitename/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
this is my htaccess file

Comment: Have you made any changes to `.htaccess` after installation ?

Comment: This is the coding in the anchor tag:  <a href="<?php echo site_url($product->slug); ?>">. The $product->slug give me the product name

Comment: I have chnaged only the site name

Comment: Have you given the proper site name ?

Comment: The site name should be exactly what you see in the url

Comment: Instead of using slug , can you see what it is giving for `a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/feed">Feeds</a>` and `a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/feed">Feeds</a>` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>BusinessPad/feed">Feed Page</a>
```

if this not works use this

```
 <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/BusinessPad/feed">Feed Page</a>
```

**Explain** :

1. `<?php echo base_url();?>//URL`
2. `BusinessPad//Controller`
3. `feed//Function`

in **1.** this will give your site URL. `http://localhost/BusinessPad/localhost/`. if you host this to live server it will come with tour domain name.

then in **2** it will call your controller which Contains  your functions.

**Note**: if you juct call your controller it will call automatically `public function index()` if you create.

then in **3** it will redirect to your function  which you exactly need.